# Memory Space Usage: Linked List Pointers vs Array Indexes

Tags: arrays, pointers, indexing, data-structures, linked-list

I am learning about linked lists and am curious how much memory space would be required for a linked list compared to that of an array with identical elements. [This page](http://www.geeksforgeeks.org/linked-list-vs-array/) lists the following as a disadvantage of linked lists:

> Extra memory space for a pointer is required with each element of the list.

But an array must also use memory for each element's index, right?

I'd guess that an index would take less memory than a pointer, but I'm curious as to what kind of ratio we would be talking about. Any thoughts?

Comment: That depends on your language - an array in its purest form doesn't need to use memory to store an index (and index can be abstracted away even with mixed arrays) - if you know how much memory every of the elements takes you can easily calculate where in memory to pick up the element at index `n` by simply calculating `n * element_size`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you're using *value-types* as array elements, then an array uses less storage.

I'll use C as an example:

#### 1. Array of values:

```
struct Value {
    int x;
};

sizeof(struct Value) == 4 bytes (assuming zero overhead)

struct Value staticArray[10]; // will consume 10 * 4 == 40 bytes
```

#### 2. If it's an array of pointers, then:

```
struct Value* staticArrayOfPointers[10];
for( size_t i = 0; i < sizeof(staticArrayOfPointers); i++ ) {
    staticArrayOfPointers[i] = calloc( sizeof(struct Value), 1 );
}
```

- The amount of memory `staticArrayOfPointers` uses depends on the size of a pointer on your system:

  - On a 32-bit system (e.g. x86) then the array itself it will use 40 bytes in a contiguous block, *plus* an additional 4 bytes for each `struct Value` element (each individually allocated somewhere in the heap (using `calloc`)) for a total of 80 bytes.
  - On a 64-bit system (e.g. AMD64)  then it will use 80 bytes, as a pointer is 8 bytes long (`10 * 8 == 80`), *plus* an additional 4 bytes for each `struct Value` element, for a total of 120 bytes.

#### 3. If it's a linked-list using inline values, using the heap:

```
struct Node {
    struct Value value; // stored inline, as a value, in the node, not elsewhere in memory
    Node* next;
}

sizeof(struct Node) == 8 bytes (assuming zero overhead and alignment, and 4-byte pointers)

struct Node* head = calloc( sizeof(struct Node), 1 ); // calloc zeroes memory
struct Node* current = head;
for( size_t i = 0; i < 10; i++ ) {
    current->next = calloc( sizeof(struct Node), 1 );
    current = current->next;
}
```

The linked-list is now at least `10 * 8` (80) bytes in memory, and potentially fragmented too, as each node could exist in different locations in memory.

#### 4. If it's a linked-list using pointers to values (also using the heap):

```
struct Node2 {
    struct Value* valuePtr;
    Node* next;
}

sizeof(struct Node2) == 8 (as a pointer is also 4 bytes), but then add another 4 bytes for the `Value` instance located elsewhere:

struct Node2* head = calloc( sizeof(struct Node2), 1 ); // calloc zeroes memory
head->valuePtr = calloc( sizeof(struct Value), 1 );
struct Node2* current = head;
for( size_t i = 0; i < 10; i++ ) {
    current->next = calloc( sizeof(struct Node2), 1 );
    current->valuePtr = calloc( sizeof(struct Value), 1 );
    current = current->next;
}
```

This version will now consume `10 * ( 8 + 4 ) == 120` bytes, but as there's more allocation going on the potential for fragmentation is also increased.

#### In summary:

- Array of values: `n * sizeof(Element)`
- Array of pointers-to-values: `n * ( sizeof(Element*) + sizeof(Element) )`
- Linked-list of values: `n * ( sizeof(Element) + sizeof(Node*) )`
- Linked-list of pointers-to-values: `n * ( sizeof(Element*) + sizeof(Element) + sizeof(Node*) )`

#### Caveats:

- It depends on the language. If it's a language like C or C++ that gives you full control over memory then you can use any of the above approaches.
- If it's Java, then only primitive-types (`int`, `double`, but not `string`) are value-types, all other types are "reference types" and use pointers internally, but because it's a GC environment you won't suffer fatal memory fragmentation... hopefully.
- If it's C# or Swift, where you can have value-types (`struct` vs `class`) then you can use all 4 options, but the pointers themselves are not exposed.
- JavaScript abstracts internal representation away - so what you think is a simple array of `Number` values *could* be any one of: a view over (what is internally) a discontiguously allocated series of sub-arrays, or a single array, or a linked-list, or something else - and in all cases each element could be a C-style `int`, or a pointer to a value stored separately, or something else entirely.